# Set the JSON Data in TextView?

Tags: android, json

I am able to get the `JSON` Data but not able to set The Value in the `TextView`.While i am setting the Data its Showing **Null Pointer Exception**.

**getUsersListData()**

```
public class Fee extends Fragment /*implements View.OnClickListener   */ {

    LinearLayout receipt1, receipt2, receipt3, receipt4;
    LinearLayout receipt1detail, receipt2detail, receipt3detail, receipt4detail;


    TextView statustextView;
    ListView listViewfees, listviewfeedetail;
    List<StudentFeeInformation> yourData = new ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation>();
    public static final String Navigation_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Api/financeApi/getAllFees";

    String master_id;
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    TextView table_data1, table_data2;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_listview, container, false);


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        receipt1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_receipt1_fee);

        //  receipt4 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_receipt4_fee);

        //  receipt1detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt1_fee);
        //  receipt2detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt2_fee);
        //  receipt3detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt3_fee);
        //  receipt4detail = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt4_fee);

        //   receipt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt2.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt3.setOnClickListener(this);
        //   receipt4.setOnClickListener(this);


        //   receipt1detail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //   receipt2detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   receipt3detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //   receipt4detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        statustextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_status);
        SessionManagement sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(getContext());
        master_id = sessionManagement.getMasterId();
        listViewfees = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_student_fees);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleTableLayout);

        table_data1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
        table_data2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);

        getUsersListData();

        return view;
    }


    private void getUsersListData() {


        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?id=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            String Descriptionlist;
                            String Amount = null;
                            ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<StudentFeeInformation> student_list_description = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String status = jsonObject.getString("Status");
                                String DateofReceiptIssued = jsonObject.getString("DateOfReciept").substring(0, 10);
                                String ReceiptNumber = jsonObject.getString("RecieptNo");
                                String FeeReceivedDate = jsonObject.getString("recivedDate").substring(0, 10);

                                String Description = jsonObject.getString("Description");
                                JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(Description);

                                for (int j = 0; j < jArray1.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray1.getJSONObject(j);

                                    Descriptionlist = jsonObjectinner.getString("des");
                                    Amount = jsonObjectinner.getString("Amount");
                                    table_data1.setText(Amount); // its Showing the Null pointer exception


                                    System.out.println(Descriptionlist);
                                    System.out.println(Amount);


                                }
                                student_list.add(new StudentFeeInformation(status, DateofReceiptIssued, ReceiptNumber, FeeReceivedDate));

                            }
                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_list.size());
                            CustomFeeListStudentAdapter customFeeListStudentAdapter = new CustomFeeListStudentAdapter(getActivity(), student_list);

                            listViewfees.setAdapter(customFeeListStudentAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                // do s.th.
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**My MOdel Class**

```
public class StudentFeeInformation implements Serializable {
    public String Status;
    public String ReceiptIssuedDate;
    public String ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    public String FeeReceivedDate;
    public String FeeDescription;
    public String Amount;


    public StudentFeeInformation(String status, String ReceiptissuedDate, String ReceiptissuedNumber, String FeereceivedDate, String amount) {
        Status = status;
        ReceiptIssuedDate = ReceiptissuedDate;
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = ReceiptissuedNumber;
        FeeReceivedDate = FeereceivedDate;
        Amount = amount;


    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedDate() {
        return ReceiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedDate(String receiptIssuedDate) {
        ReceiptIssuedDate = receiptIssuedDate;
    }

    public String getReceiptIssuedNumber() {
        return ReceiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public void setReceiptIssuedNumber(String receiptIssuedNumber) {
        ReceiptIssuedNumber = receiptIssuedNumber;
    }

    public String getFeeReceivedDate() {
        return FeeReceivedDate;
    }

    public void setFeeReceivedDate(String feeReceivedDate) {
        FeeReceivedDate = feeReceivedDate;
    }


    public String getFeeDescription() {
        return FeeDescription;
    }

    public void setFeeDescription(String feeDescription) {
        FeeDescription = feeDescription;
    }


    public String getAmount() {
        return Amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        Amount = amount;
    }


}
```

**my JSON**

```
[
  {
    "MasterID": "E0017",
    "StdID": 111,
    "Status": "U",
    "AmountPaid": 6645,
    "Class": 8,
    "DateOfReciept": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Description": "[{\"des\":\"Admission\",\"Amount\":300},{\"des\":\"Monthly Fee\",\"Amount\":5400},{\"des\":\"Exam Fee\",\"Amount\":200},{\"des\":\"Extra Charge\",\"Amount\":400},{\"des\":\"Late Charge\",\"Amount\":345}]",
    "RecieptNo": 1011,
    "NAME": "Uzumaki Naruto",
    "recivedDate": "2017-03-10T00:00:00",
    "reciever": "Cynthia Irwin"
  },
  {
    "MasterID": "E0017",
    "StdID": 111,
    "Status": "U",
    "AmountPaid": 5600,
    "Class": 8,
    "DateOfReciept": "2017-03-01T00:00:00",
    "Description": "[{\"des\":\"Exam Fee\",\"Amount\":200},{\"des\":\"Monthly Fee\",\"Amount\":5400}]",
    "RecieptNo": 1012,
    "NAME": "Uzumaki Naruto",
    "recivedDate": "2017-03-06T00:00:00",
    "reciever": "Cynthia Irwin"
  }
]
```

**layout**

```
 <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/simpleTableLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:stretchColumns="1"> <!-- stretch the second column of the layout-->


                        <TableRow

                            android:id="@+id/firstRow"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                            <TextView

                                android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_description"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left|center"
                                android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Sports"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <TextView

                                android:id="@+id/student_profile_fee_amount"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="left|center"
                                android:paddingLeft="70dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:text="Sports"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
```

**logcat**setting outside loop

```
  3-16 16:31:01.037 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: DescriptionlistAdmission
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Amount300
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: table_data1 null
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: DescriptionlistMonthly Fee
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Amount5400
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: table_data1 null
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: DescriptionlistExam Fee
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Amount200
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: table_data1 null
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: DescriptionlistExtra Charge
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Amount400
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: table_data1 null
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: DescriptionlistLate Charge
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: Amount345
03-16 16:31:03.032 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/TAG: table_data1 null
03-16 16:31:03.033 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-16 16:31:03.033 9722-9722/com.example.user.mis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.example.user.mis, PID: 9722
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.example.user.mis.fragment.Fee$1.onResponse(Fee.java:175)
                                                                        at com.example.user.mis.fragment.Fee$1.onResponse(Fee.java:130)
                                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

> I know the the Value is null, but don't able to fix the issue?

Comment: did u initialize `table_data1` properly?

Comment: check your table_data1 is null?

Comment: table_data1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_description);
        table_data2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_fee_amount);

Comment: I think you didn't initialize` table_data1`. have you initialize it?

Comment: yes sir .i have initialized it properly

Comment: post your json data

Comment: `String Description = jsonObject.getString("Description");
                                JSONArray jArray1 = new JSONArray(Description);`
This does not make any sense. Is your "Description" tag an array or a simple String?

Comment: i have posted JSON Data

Comment: @Suman see my edited answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42831455/6676466

Comment: I am getting the JSON Response on the Logcat
3-16 15:55:57.718 13402-13402/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: Admission
03-16 15:55:57.718 13402-13402/com.example.user.mis I/System.out: 300
03-16 15:55:57.718 13402-13402/com.example.user.mis I/System.out:

Comment: @user2025187 the JSON Response is printed on the Logcat.But dont be able to set Value

Comment: Check log for amount value

Comment: System.out.println(Descriptionlist);                                    System.out.println(Amount); prints data

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialise table_data1 if not do this

```
TextView table_data1 = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
```

if this done already publish your full code :)

Answer (score 0):

- you can check this `TextView table_data1` is null or not by writing log.

  Log.e("TestTAG", "table_data1=="+table_data1)
- if it is printing null then check it is initialized before calling **WebService**, if you are doing all correct then check that view from where you are finding id of table_data1 contains this `TextView` or not?

## EDIT

check your layout `student_fees_listview` has this TextView `student_profile_fee_description`
if not then you are `inflating` wrong layout.

Comment: student_profile_fee_description is on the  Fragment_fee layout.  student_fees_listview is the ListView man

Comment: That is the exact problem.
You are inflating wrong layout here `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_fees_listview, container, false);` 

If used TextView is not in the inflated layout then it will definitely throws `NullpointerException` because android unable to find this `TextView` on given layout.

Comment: I have listView , which should be populated by the JSON  ,the on the LIST Items  i have used the TableLayout .How can i do that?

Comment: please look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807075/parse-json-data-in-the-listview-which-is-within-the-listview

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828823/populate-tablelayout-row-dynamically

Comment: It means there will be 2 classes and 2 layouts and you are mismatching those layout with each other.

Comment: yes exactly.two layout but i have only one class other than Adapter

Comment: There are simple two steps - 
1. Your fragment will set the adapter after parsing the data.
2. Adapter class will set the data.

No need to set the data inside Fragment because Adapter is doing so.
 Thats it

Comment: I am able to set the value.Can the tableLayout be used same as the listView.that means as the listItems added automatically.can we do similar as listView in the TableLayout?

Comment: **No**, Both are diff things,` Listview` is more easy than `TableLayout`.
Preferring `ListView` will be good.

Comment: if i have to use listView within the listView.How can this be achieved?

Comment: Every `ListView` has its own Adapter. and Every Adapter has its separate layout. Just do what the same for inner `ListView` as doing for outer `ListView`. Here is the best example for you. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: Can't i use Dynamic Linear Layout .So that the items added in the LinearLayout through the JSON Data

Comment: ListView
        textView 
        textView
        ImageView
        ListView
            listItems 
            listItems
How can this be done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int Amount = jsonObjectinner.getInt("Amount");
Log.d("TAG","Descriptionlist"+Descriptionlist);
Log.d("TAG","Amount"+Amount);

if(table_data1!=null)
{
    Log.d("TAG","table_data1 not null");
    table_data1.setText(Amount+""); 
}
else
{
    Log.d("TAG","table_data1 null");
}
```

Comment: @Suman your are set value inside for loop .. so only last value set to textview...if above code  not working then post your findviewbyid for table_data1 code

Comment: Its is showing null value.
this is executed Log.d("TAG","table_data1 null");

Comment: null  value or Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: null value. i have added the layout .please check

Comment: Amount = jsonObjectinner.getInt("Amount"); change string to int , check log for Amount.Set value table_data1.setText(Amount+"");

Comment: Your table_data1  not null.Your are no getting Amount  value

Comment: when i add this  table_data1.setText(Amount+"");.i get

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828823/populate-tablelayout-row-dynamically

Comment: send  amount log cat.You are not getting amount value ...check amount value 1st

Comment: where amount value is printer in logcat? 1st print both values amount and des and then set to textview

Comment: try to set  table_data1.setText(Amount);  outside forloop

Comment: actually i am using the TableLayout on the ListView_item_row

Answer (score 0):

Make a class for response using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
After that make object of your class then by calling get methods you can get each value separately. Then you can use it wherever you want. Hope it helps you. Just visit the link above and paste your json you will have idea how to proceed. Serialize your response data properly.